# How to reduce the amount of memory consumed by .NET apps?

Tags: .net, optimization, performance

This question escaped my mind last night, but I remember it again. Is it possible that in the development of a vb.net application that you can reduce the amount of memory that it will consume once you deploy it.

We are making a simple system that we will deploy in a small company (for free) but we don't know if the computer hardware in the company would be fit to run our application. Is it possible, to reduce the load of the app on the computer?

Comment: Yes.  It's called optimization.  What specifically are you asking?

Comment: I'm asking for the techniques that I could employ so that the system would consume lesser amount of memory. Or system resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really not possible to answer your question, given such a severe lack of information.

However, there are things that you can do to figure this out.

First, given that the company is so small, it should be easy to take an inventory of the machines that the application will run on and determine the lowest-common-denominator in terms of resources on any particular machine.

Then, you can code against those specs.

Additionally, you can use things like logging, the event log, as well as performance counters to help determine the performance of your application when it runs on users machines.  Once you have that information, if there are bottlenecks, you can spot them and address the specific areas that are slowing down the process.